# Very wide UITextField in a UIScroller moves to right initially

Tags: ios, xcode

All,

I have a wide UITextField with a wide Canvas (UIView) together in a scroller and Stack. The structure is as follows:

```
UIScrollView (scrolls both horizontally and vertically)
    UIStackView (vertical)
        UITextField 
        UIView (the canvas that displays all sorts of visual elements)
```

The UIView is 2000 pixels wide, as is the UITextField. They are both supposed to scroll together - hence them both living in the stack inside the scroller.

When I click in the UITextField to begin editing, whether it is empty or already has text, it zooms off to the far right end.

I have used something like this to try and control the position:

```
    public void MoveCursorToVisibleIfRequired()
        {
            //  Pixel position of cursor
            CGPoint cursorPosition = NoteTitle.GetCaretRectForPosition(NoteTitle.SelectedTextRange.Start).Location;
            //  Is it currently visible in the scroll view (with at least 20 px?)
            var scrollPos = ContentScrollView.ContentOffset;
            var scrollWidth = ContentScrollView.Frame.Width;
            if (cursorPosition.X+20 < scrollPos.X || cursorPosition.X > scrollPos.X + scrollWidth - 20)
            {
                //  Lets move it into the middle of the text region (if possible)
                cursorPosition.X -= (int)(ContentScrollView.Frame.Width / 2);
                //  Make sure we are not going too far
                if (cursorPosition.X < 0)
                    cursorPosition.X = 0;
                ContentScrollView.SetContentOffset(cursorPosition, true);
            }
        }
```

When the cursor position gets too close to the left or right of the visible portion of the UITextView, the cursor is moved to the middle by moving the scroller. That works well, and I have attached it to:

- EditingChanged
- EditingDidBegin (for when you click in the text field)
- Cursor movement (by adding an observer to changes in "selectedTextRange")

As I type, the textfield periodically animates/moves the cursor to the middle.

Weirdly, the UIScrollView (and therefore the UITextField and UIView) is zipping off to the far right when I click in the UITextField to give it focus, and also when the UIViewController loads and I give the UITextField first responder status.

I am positive that my `MoveCursorToVisibleIfRequired` function is not misbehaving somehow because I have breakpointed it to check values, *and* this behaviour pre-dated that function.

Any thoughts why a scroller containing a very wide text field and UIView might zoom off to the far right on getting first responder status?

Thx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a workaround. It doesn't resolve the question of WHY a UITextField getting focus causes the containing scroller to zoom off to the right... but it does make things work.

a) Embed the UITextField in a UIView. So the hierarchy becomes this:

```
UIScrollView (scrolls both horizontally and vertically)
    UIStackView (vertical)
        UIView
            UITextField 
        UIView (the canvas that displays all sorts of visual elements)
```

b) Make the UITextField a dynamic size - so it resizes based on the contained text.

c) Ensure its parent UIView full width (2000 px wide).

Now clicking in the UITextField does not cause crazy scrolling. However because the UITextField is small - there is a lot of white space to its right (the parent UIView).

d) Add a Tap gesture recogniser on the parent UIView that sets First Responder to the UITextField. This replicates the functionality of clicking anywhere in a text field to get focus.

```
    var vw = NoteTitle.Superview;
    var tap = new UITapGestureRecognizer((gest) =>
            {
                if (gest.State == UIGestureRecognizerState.Ended)
                    NoteTitle.BecomeFirstResponder();
            });
    vw.AddGestureRecognizer(tap);
```